# Why are my UITableViews misplaced on the y-axis when adding them programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have as simple setup where I have a view controller embedded in a `UINavigationController`. On this view controller, I want to display multiple `tableView`s next to each other (horizontally). I am creating and adding the `tableView`s in `viewDidLoad`. It works well except that there is an issue with the `y`-position of every `tableView` except for the first one.

When creating the `tableView`s programmatically, the first `tableView` is always properly displayed right below the `UINavigationBar`. However all of the others are displayed "behind" the `UINavigationBar` even though the `y`-coordinate is equal to `0` in all of the `tableView`s.

This is what it looks like when you run it on the simulator (note that the `tableView` itself has a green `backgroundColor`):

[image]

And this is the code for it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var tableViews: [UITableView] = [] // maintained only for debugging purposes

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tableViewCount: Int = 5
        createTableViews(tableViewCount)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print(#function, tableViews)
    }

    func createTableView(count: Int) {
        let width = Int(self.view.bounds.width)/count

        for i in 0..<count {
            let x = width * i
            let y = 0
            let height = Int(view.bounds.height)
            let frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y , width: width, height: height)
            let tableView = UITableView(frame: frame, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
            tableView.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            view.addSubview(tableView)
            tableView.tag = i

            tableViews.append(tableView)
        }
    }
}
```

I am only maintaining the `tableViews` property so that I can print them in `viewDidAppear`. The console output in `viewDidAppear` shows that all my `tableView`s have the same `y` position on their frames (= `0`).

I did find an easy (yet hacky) fix for this. All I have to do is set the first `y` to `0` and the rest to `64` (which is the height of the status bar plus the height of the navigation bar). Like so:

```
let y = i == 0 ? 0 : 64
```

Does anyone have an idea why the `tableView`s are being misplaced? According to my understanding, all `tableView`s should be displayed right below the navigation bar, as this is the vertical origin of the view controller's `view`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to my understanding, all tableViews should be displayed right below the navigation bar, as this is the vertical origin of the view controller's view?

This is only the case in my experience if you set `myNavigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false`. If the navigation bar is translucent, the top of your view is still the top of the screen.

On a side note, you should definitely look into laying these views out via auto layout, rather than this hacky frame math. Would simplify your code a lot.

Comment: Doing `myNavigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false` fixed the issue, thanks for that!